# Track post views

Tags: php, http

I am working on a project where only title of posts are shown on main page and on clicking the title, full post is loaded on another page `posts.php` code for this is:

```
<a href="posts.php?postId=<?php echo $row['posts_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
```

Is there any method to track how many times post with specific id was loaded on `posts.php`. In simple words I want to track how many times full post has been viewed on `posts.php` page, someone suggested count HTTP requests with this URL. So please guide me on this just few lines on how the thing works can help me a lot.

Comment: for this you'll need a new column in your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is create a new column in your table, suppose it's name is 'hits'. Set the default value of it to 0 while creating a new row everytime.

```
$id = $_GET['postId'];
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE post_id = $id"; //Suppose your table name is posts
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new column in your database table like `view_count`. When you get data from database you can update `view_count` like

`update table_name set view_count = view_count + 1 where post_id = $_GET['postId']`

it will increment `view_count` every time when page will load.

Answer (score 0):

You insert a code on top of your script *post.php* in order to count visitors.

Something like: http://hibbard.eu/how-to-make-a-simple-visitor-counter-using-php

If you prefer Database, you just have to change your code.

Comment: that page doesn't exist  check link again